# Best way to add Firebase pods

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

We are currently using **Firebase/Performance** and **Firebase/Analytics** in our app. However, I just noticed that by including **Firebase/Analytics** rather than **FirebaseAnalytics**, it removes the Firebase dependency which we don't need it seems.

I was wondering if it is ok to indeed remove that dependency and only have **FirebaseAnalytics** and **FirebasePerformance** specifically.

Also, I couldn't find anywhere a history of these two pod history. Indeed there's only the global changelog page that gives infos on the new Firebase releases, and gives infos about the "sub" pods, but without giving the version number of those sub pods. Is there any place where I could find infos about those?

Answer (score 1):

The slash in `Firebase/Analytics` and `Firebase/Performance` indicates a subspec of the Firebase pod.  See the published Firebase podspec [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.30.0/Firebase.podspec.json#L65) and the source [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firebase.podspec).

As you noticed, if you specify the dependent `FirebaseAnalytics` and `FirebasePerformance`, the Firebase pod won't be installed which provides access to the Firebase module and the ability to `import Firebase`.

It is recommended and the some of the docs assume that the Firebase pod is available, but if you're fine to add specific imports for the Firebase APIs used, it should be fine to skip.